# Allowing multiple models to access a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a controller that I am calling

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

at the beginning of. However, I also have a model, admin, that should access this controller, i.e.

```
before_action :authenticate_admin!
```

How can I make it so either one can access the controller?

Comment: It sounds quite odd. Why would you want to authenticate the user in the model? It's a clear violation of MVC principles.

Comment: Why would you need this by the way?

Comment: security level checks are at controller level or in views when displaying things, so that one cannot access the things he don't have access to. you should authenticate user in controller rather than verifying the rights inside admin. that should be the practise.

Comment: Sorry I believe I phrased this oddly. I am authenticating within the controller,  I was just trying to specify that I have multiple models that include devise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise offers you helper methods `user_signed_in?` and `admin_signed_in?` for the `User` model and `Admin` model, respectively.

You can write custom filter in `ApplicationController`, and apply the filter in the concrete controller on demand.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  class AuthorizationException < StandardError
  end

  rescue_from AuthorizationException do
    render text: "Access Denied", status: :unauthorized
  end

  protected
  def authenticate_user_or_admin!
    unless user_signed_in? or admin_signed_in?
      raise AuthorizationException.new
    end
  end
end
```

You can use the filter `authenticate_user_or_admin!` in your controller now.